# How can you define and enforce a Neo4J graph's schema?

Tags: neo4j, rdbms, graph-databases

I want to achieve, with a Neo4j graph a RDBMS's ability to define and enforce a known schema. We know what our graph should look like (all the edge types and node types). So we simply want to prevent someone (developer/user) from adding an edge or node type which is "invalid" i.e. not part of the defined graph schema. How can we enforce a graphs schema? Note I am not asking about how to enforce the properties of an edge or a graph but simply how to enforce that the graph is made up if a specific set of known edge and node types. 
Please help

Comment: You can also look into ecosystem projects like http://beta.sylvadb.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably be done on the application side. Build a wrapper/API that enforces this sort of thing, and make the developers use it. Sorry for the short answer...

Comment: Why would you say "probably should be done on the application side"? Doesn't this create a scenario where every application that touches a database becomes responsible for enforcing the rules? At that point, every database you create will require the creation of a layer of software to enforce the schema rules you want to enforce, in every application language that will be using the database. This has to be done not because it is a better way, but because the database falls short of typical requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the language drivers or frameworks listed here provide means to define a schema:

http://www.neo4j.org/drivers

For Java we developed structr (https://github.com/structr/structr) where you define your schema in Java beans. You could start f.e. with the simple Maven archetype as shown in this screencast: http://vimeo.com/53235075

Cheers
Axel

Answer (score 0):

It has to happen in a layer above Neo4j. I've been building one of those layers ([Restagraph](https://github.com/equill/restagraph)), which puts a REST interface on top of it.

It's a mite less mature than Structr, but may be worth a look. I package it in a Docker image, and it's designed so you can easily define your own schema in YAML files.